# Where does Moses say the things which Paul attributes to him in Acts 26:22-23?

Tags: acts, paul, moses, messiah, intertextuality

In Acts 26:22-23, Paul says that

> I stand here...saying nothing but what the prophets and Moses said would come to pass: that the Christ must suffer and that, by being the first to rise from the dead, he would proclaim light both to our people and to the Gentiles.

It seems like there are three claims which Paul says Moses and the prophets made:

1. The Christ must suffer
2. The Christ would be the first to rise from the dead
3. The Christ would proclaim light both to the Jews and to the Gentiles

Furthermore, Paul claims that both *Moses and the prophets* made these claims. My question is: Where in the Old Testament are these claims made (explicitly)?

I have looked around and found answers such as [this article](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7118/where-did-moses-write-about-jesus) from the Christianity StackExchange, but the answer of Moses' writings about Jesus are very vague and unconvincing (e.g. reading Jesus into manna or the water which sprung from a rock). Such an analysis seems to be guilty of reading meaning back into the passages after-the-fact.

I would be interested in any answers addressing my original question or my doubts about the vagueness of the references found in the article I linked. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever studied the Sanctuary Service as setup at Sinai? This is exactly what it is about. Also, It says "Moses AND the Prophets"

Comment: "Christ must suffer and that, by being the first to rise from the dead" Did Paul forget about Lazarus, here, or is he using some specialized meaning for "rise from the dead"?

Comment: @nick012000, Lazarus was raised, Jesus was the first to rise.  I think that's the distinction Paul is making.

Answer (score 9):

First, "Moses and the prophets", or sometimes, "the Law of Moses and the prophets", is a common hendiadys meaning what we now call the OT Hebrew scriptures. John 1:45, Luke 16:29, 31, 24:44, Acts 13:15, 26:22, 28:23, Rom 3:21, etc.

There are many examples of where the NT writers quoted the OT to show that Jesus fulfilled OT prophecies such as: Matt 1:22, 2:6, 16, 3:15, 4:14, 8:17, 12:17-21, 13:13-15, 35, 21:4, 41, 42, 26:24, 52-56, 27:8, 9, 35, Mark 1:2, 9:13, 14:21, 49, Luke 3:4, 4:17, 12;14, 24:25-27, 44, 45, John 4:25, 26, 29, 12:38, Acts 2:29, 30, 8:31-34, 18:27, 28, Rom 1:1, 2, 1 Cor 15:3, 4, etc.  (There are many more!)

When it comes to the specific predictions of Paul in Acts 26 we have:

1. **Suffering servant**: Isa 53, Ps 22 (cited in Matt 27:35, 43, 46, Mark 15:24, 34, Luke 23:34, John 19:24, etc)
2. **Resurrection of Messiah** is prophesied in places such as: Ps 16:10, Isa 53:3, 11, 12, Job 19:25, etc.  See also 1 Cor 15:4.  See also Matt 16:21, 17:23, 20:19, Mark 9:31, 10:34, Luke 18:33, 9:22, Col 1:18, etc.
3. **Light to the Jews and Gentiles**: Isa 9:2, 3 (quoted by Matt 4:12-17, Mark 1:14, 15, Luke 4:14, 15); Isa 42:6, 49:6.  See also Acts 13:47, Hab 2:14 and Isa 56:6, 7.

Thus, Paul's statement about Messiah's details predicted in the OT was entirely accurate.

Comment: Good use of hendiadys, upvoted +1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question still about claim #2. I looked at Ps 16:10, Isa 53:3, Isa 11, and Job 19:25, but none of these seem to come close to prophesying that Jesus would be the first to rise from the dead (like Paul says the OT predicts). Can you please further explain these references?

Comment: @TonyBai - the OT just predicts that Messiah would rise from the dead.  The "firstborn" of the dead come from Col 1:18.  There were others who were raised from the dead before Christ (eg, Lazarus, the widow of Nain's son etc) but Jesus was first in the sense of the most important, see 1 Cor 15:10-20.

Answer (score 5):

We could render Paul's statement to mean:

- Moses said all these things & the prophets said all these things
  OR
- Between Moses & the prophets all these things were said

The former cannot be unambiguously reconstructed based on the Old Testament; the best we can do there is acknowledge that there are multiple instances in the New Testament where a prophetic/scriptural statement is cited for which we have no surviving record.

Given the extreme destruction of Jewish lands, structure, and records brought about by the Roman-Jewish war (especially the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70), it should come as no surprise that there are records they had then that we do not have now.

The latter option can be reconstructed reasonably well from the Old Testament:

1. The Christ must suffer (Isaiah 53: 3-7)
2. The Christ would be the first to rise from the dead (Job 19:25, Isaiah 53:10-12, that He would be resurrected is clear, that He would be the first is probably the least clear--in the OT--of the statements)
3. The Christ would proclaim light both to the Jews and to the Gentiles (Isaiah 9:2-3, Habakkuk 2:14)

(If there were a more specific teaching of the resurrection by Moses, I presume Jesus would have cited it in Luke 20:38)

Since Paul is referring to his preaching in general, not just the 3 points cited, he certainly can claim to have taught from Moses & prophets. In other words, Paul says his message is based on Moses & the prophets, not that just these 3 specifics are from Moses & the prophets.

**Conclusion**

There's no reason to require Paul's statement to mean "Moses said each of these things"; Paul's point is that his teachings are firmly rooted in the Jewish scriptures.

Comment: I do not know why such an answer as this was downvoted to I have unvoted it to balance things up.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Agreed. +1.

Comment: @Dottard - sure, if you think this answer deserves YOUR upvote, I have no problem with that.  But upvoting just to annul someone else's opinion is kind of arrogant.  Sometimes, other people have opinions that are different from yours, but still valid.

Comment: @Dawood if you believe there is a shortcoming in my answer I'd be very interested in your feedback. I took Dottard's actions as respectful rather than arrogant. Downvotes are helpful when accompanied by a comment; since no comment was given it left me unable to use the community's wisdom to improve my post. When I see posts sitting at -1 votes with no reason given I frequently upvote them as well.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod I don't have a strong opinion either way on your answer.  I did not vote, up or down.  But _somebody_ does have a strong opinion - that person felt strongly enough to apply a downvote.  My objection is to Dottard deciding to use their vote to annul an opinion that they admitted to not understanding.  That's why I said - if you feel an answer deserves an upvote, then upvote it.  But voting just to annul someone else's opinion is extremely arrogant.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod and if your normal practice is to upvote answers for NO OTHER REASON than that they currently have -1 votes, that makes a mockery of the voting system.  It rewards bad answers more than it rewards answers that are neither good nor bad.  I'm kind of disgusted to read that there's actually someone who does this.

Comment: @Dawood thanks for your thoughts--I'm not disgusted that you disagree. I should clarify something though--I frequently see -1 posts that are clearly deficient--I don't upvote those. If I see a decent post at -1...or a post that has been attacked for theological reasons, I certainly do try to support them. Having been the recipient of multiple attacks of serial downvoting myself, I want to encourage decent posts by voting for them, even if I don't always agree with them. When people's efforts don't get votes, too often they leave. We're a small site and can't afford to play that game.

Comment: Sure, if they're decent posts that _independently_ deserve an upvote, then sure, upvote them.  What I like to do is to decide, when I read a post, whether I feel it deserves an upvote or a downvote, _without_ looking at the existing vote tally.  Because _my_ opinion isn't worth more or less than anyone else's.  In other words, vote my own opinion, not somebody else's.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - I upvoted because, as stated above, I thought HTTR gave a good and helpful answer and thus was mystified as the why it was downvoted.  If it have been a poor answer I would not have upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to comment about Resurrection - Jesus First fruit of resurrection. after Lazarus brought back to life - He died again, same thing with Son of widow, same as in person fell on Elisha's bone, Small girl Peter prayed. Resurrection - You have won victory over death and brought back to life - your spirit being - and you will get heavenly body - perishable get imperishable. Whereas Lazarus, other people who are bought back to life did not have imperishable body as Jesus has. We all will get resurrected bodies at Jesus second coming.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/47503)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion about the Annointed One's rise from the dead as being the first. How could he be, when even brfore he was crucified, Lazarus and a host of others by Jesus himself and God and prophets had been risen from the dead?

It was not the body's death that is referred to by Paul in (Colosians 1:18). It was the spiritual death, which by Adam's sin we all inherited (Romans 5:12,14). Jesus was the first to come out of that death when God annointed him after his baptism with his own spirit of Wisdom which John referred to as the Logos (John 1:1, Hebrews 5:4-7). Which Jesus and John the Baptist saw coming over him in the form of a dove.

Spiritual Death! The death that God promised would occur should Adam disobey God's commandment (Genesis 2:17). That death was God vacating his "place of rest" in Adam (Iasaiah 59:2), removing from him all the glory he had embewed him with. That glory that David pondered in Psalm 8 and God lamented in Isaiah 14:12 and Ezekiel 28 (which the Greco Roman church twisted out of context).

That was the resurrection that Paul was talking about, the resurrection from the spiritual death that Adam brought upon his offspring.

That's the resurrection to be celebrated  as far as I'm concerned.

Truly, what Chrisiianity should be celebrating is not Christs resurrection from the grave, but that he gave up his life to save his Bride, something which Adam did not do in Eden. The mistery that Paul alluded to in (Ephesians 5:32). That Christ relied on God to raise him up after 3 nights and 3 days after he gave up his spirit, was nothing new. For he trusted in him who had the power to raise him up (Romans 8:11).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JohnnyR According to Colossians 1:18 Jesus Christ was the firstborn from the realm of the dead in a permanent fashion. This is backed up at Revelation 1:5. This also implies the idea of opening the way for others to follow. Moreover, it was through Jesus' death that He conquered death. Mark 12:27), Acts 20:28. Spiritual death is the separation of the soul from God caused by sin. Isaiah 59:2, "But your iniquities have made a separation between you and your God."

Comment: @Mr. Bond  I agree with your comment, and we are pretty much in agreement. However, one claim you make does not hold water with citations you provide.  That being,  with your sentence: "Moreover, it was through Jesus' death that He conquered death. Mark 12:27), Acts 20:28." 
The citations you provide do not speak to or support your claim that "it was through Jesus' death that He conquered death."

Comment: @Johnny I think you misunderstand my point. By Jesus going to the cross He conquered death. As the "God Man" He purchased the Church with His blood. Acts 20:28. Also read Hebrews 2:14-15, "He Himself likewise also partook of the same, (that is flesh and blood,) that through death He might render powerless him who had (past tense) the power of death, that is the devil, vs15, and might deliver those who through fear of death were subject to slavery all their lives." Then there is Revelation 1:18, and the living One; and I was dead and behold I am alive forevermore, and I have the keys of death.